# python feedparser and getting multiple categories (category) within a item

Tags: python, feedparser

```
import feedparser
import webbrowser

feed = feedparser.parse("https://seekingalpha.com/feed.xml")
feed_entries = feed.entries

for entry in feed.entries:

   article_title = entry.title
   article_link = entry.link
   article_published_at = entry.published # Unicode string
   article_published_at_parsed = entry.published_parsed # Time object
   e = entry.category

   print ("{}[{}]".format(article_title, article_link))
   print ("Published at {}".format(article_published_at))
```

In the above I'm only able to get the first of the category elements.  I would like to list them all but most of all just the "symbol' ones.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

All the categories can be found in `entry.tag` but will not include the `type` to identify the `symbol` category you are looking for. If that is something you want adding that is simple.

```py
for entry in feed.entries:
   # ...
   e = [t.get('term') for t in entry.tags]
```